# resize и разрешение браузера

Tags: javascript, if, resize

Не могу понять в чем проблема с работой кода. Все работает отлично, пока я не сменю на iPad (в принципе любой планшет) разрешение, то есть не покручу экраном.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(min-width:320px) and (max-width:978px)").matches) {
    $(".navItem a").click(function(){
      $("#nav1").slideUp();
    });
  }
});
```

Получается, что код отлично обрабатывается, если я держу вертикально планшет, заходит в блок IF в консоле выводил разрешение, отлично его получает, но стоит мне перевернуть планшет в горизонтальную ориентацию, у нас получается `1024px` разрешение, и код все равно обрабатывается. Тем самым скрывает мне блок навигации, и я больше не смогу нажать на кнопки меню.

Коротко о самой сути кода. У меня есть меню сайта, которое для компов горизонтальное вверху, а для мобильных скрывается за иконкой "гамбургера". Нажав на которую оно вертикально выползает вниз. У меня концепция сайта одностраничника, поэтому ссылки якорные, и нету рефреша сайта. Идет плавная прокрутка к якорю, но он закрыт весь этим выдвенутым меню. Вот поэтому его надо скрыть после нажатия на ссылку. Этот код что ниже, скрывает, но почему то он срабатывает и тогда, когда не должен сработать. Ведь если его запустить сразу на компе, он в блок IF не пускает. Если с горизонтального режима планшета запустить его тоже все ок, если перевернуть в портретный, тоже все работает на ура, он видит уменьшение разрешения и заходит в блок IF. Но обратно после горизонтального в портретный начинает фигней страдать. Перестает обрабатывать IF а просто всегда работает хоть и условие не подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

Вы назначаете обработчик `click` внутри обработчика `resize`. Как только Ваш `if` выполнится больше одного раза, `click` будет вызывать все добавленные функции - столько раз, сколько они были добавлены. А, ну и когда `if` не выполняется, уже добавленный обработчик (или обработчики) `click` все равно будут выстреливать.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $(".navItem a").off("click");
  if( ... ) {
    $(".navItem a").click(function(){
      $("#nav1").slideUp();
    });
  }
});
```

Вот еще такая мысль, может быть Вам подойдет. Не лучше ли будет развернуть логику:

```
$(".navItem a").click(function(){
  if(window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia("(min-width:320px) and (max-width:978px)").matches) {
    $("#nav1").slideUp();
  }
});
```

Тогда обработчик `resize` вообще не нужен.

Comment: Я вам безмерно сильно благодарен! Вы просто спаситель мой. Уже 4 часа сижу мучаюсь с этой проблемой. Добавил по вашему совету $(".navItem a").off("click");  И да, действительно, надо off вынести до if

Comment: @ВладимирТытыкало - рад помочь. Слева от ответа находится знак "галочка" - имеет смысл по ней щелкнуть, если в ответе содержится решение Вашей задачи.

Comment: Да конечно. Вопрос более чем просто решен. Но еще и очень грамотно, без посланий на курсы повышения квалификации.

Comment: Не, не получиться так. У меня изначально так и было в IF. Если без RESIZE, тогда не будет улавливать разворот планшета (телефона). У меня горизонтальное меню как раз уже на повернутом планшете срабатывает. И если нажать на любую ссылку горизонтального меню, то оно скроется))) И больше не будет на что нажимать, ведь "гамбургер" доступен только для экраном меньше 978px, а это портретный режим планшета